# How can I create an envelope with the DocuSign API if I get the error "Invalid request body"?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create and send an envelope, but I keep getting this message:
"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY:"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'emailSubject', line 1, position 150."}"

I'm thinking the mistake is somewhere here, but I can't find it (I'm new to JSON and the DocuSign API):

```
{
"documents" : 
[
    {
        "documentBase64" : "DocData",
        "documentId" : 1,
        "fileExtension" : "pdf",
        "name" : "DocuSignTestingProposal.pdf"
    }
],
"emailSubject" : "Replace with Template EMAIL",
"recipients" : 
{
    "signers" : 
    [
        {
            "email" : "mbust@email.com",
            "name" : "MBUST",
            "recipientId" : 1,
            "routingOrder" : 1,
            "tabs" : 
            {
                "dateTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "anchorString" : "**Date1Here**",
                        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
                        "anchorXOffset" : 1,
                        "anchorYOffset" : 1,
                        "documentId" : 1,
                        "fontSize" : "Size12",
                        "height" : 30,
                        "pageNumber" : 1,
                        "recipientId" : 1,
                        "width" : 100
                    }
                ],
                "signHereTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "anchorString" : "**Sign1Here**",
                        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
                        "anchorXOffset" : 1,
                        "anchorYOffset" : 1,
                        "documentId" : 1,
                        "pageNumber" : 1,
                        "recipientId" : 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
"status" : "sent"
```

}

The full request I'm using is this:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/XXXXAccount#XXXX/envelopes
--request POST
--header "Authorization: Bearer {{TOKEN}}"
--header Content-Type: application/json
--data {"documents":[{"documentBase64":"DocData","documentId":1,"fileExtension":"pdf","name":"DocuSignTestingProposal.pdf"}],"emailSubject":"Replace with Template EMAIL","recipients":{"signers":[{"email":"mbust@email.com","name":"MBUST","recipientId":1,"routingOrder":1,"tabs":{"dateTabs":[{"anchorString":"**Date1Here**","anchorUnits":"pixels","anchorXOffset":1,"anchorYOffset":1,"documentId":1,"fontSize":"Size12","height":30,"pageNumber":1,"recipientId":1,"width":100}],"signHereTabs":[{"anchorString":"**Sign1Here**","anchorUnits":"pixels","anchorXOffset":1,"anchorYOffset":1,"documentId":1,"pageNumber":1,"recipientId":1}]}}]},"status":"sent"}
```

Getting the token and the account number worked fine. But trying to create the envelope is taking me hours and can't find the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that your request looks ok. I suspect that your shell or something else is making a substitution along the path between your shell command and what DocuSign receives.

Another potential problem is the document contents. Are you Base64 encoding the document's data?

To see what DocuSign is actually receiving, use the [API Request Logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) feature.

If that doesn't help, then please update (edit) your question with the actual request from the log output.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Larry. It was something making a substitution of sorts along the path. I'm using FileMaker to send the request, and the solution was to add a @ sign before the cURL data variable in the curl options (ie., "--data @$data"). That fixed it. Thanks!